# MicroProgramming - Decrement jump not Zero

Tags: microprocessors

I'm trying to get my head around Micro Programming and OpCodes. I'm looking at DJNZ or Decrement Jump Not Zero. I've been trying to get this to work with no luck. My code with irrelevant parts removed is as follows.

```
044              alu:=ac                    If Z then goto 79
079              ac:=ac+(-1)  read         Goto 80
080     mar:=ac               write        Goto 0
```

My listing for OPCodes is this

DESP: sp:=sp-y

JNZE: if ac /= then pc:=x

So far I believe I have it to jump on not Zero to 79, then it might do a decrement and write back. I'm unsure.

I'm using this to test

```
begin:  loco   8

loop1: jnze loop1
loop2: jump loop2
```

With this output

[image]

If someone can say if I'm on the correct lines and then help me implement the jump on NOT zero and give me a pointer on the correct way to decrement and write back it would be fantastic.

Unsure if this is the correct site, and I was unsure for the tags as well so if someone could fix or point me in correct direction would be great.